# An exception proves the universal truth

Tags: logic

Can I ask a logical question here? I [had a dispute](https://superuser.com/a/214891/110460) with somebody who claims that "you need 3 DIMMs for 3 channel motherboard". I presented an example when 4 channels also work. He says that my case is an exception, whereas his rule is universal. Can this be true? Can he be proven wrong? Is it mathematical or medical question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did he mean "3 or more"?  If so, he's correct.

If he meant "precisely 3", you're correct.

It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Your dispute is probably not the case you think it is.  Your disputant here could suggest that what you have is a case in which your proposed motherboard is capable of running in Triple-channel mode with an additional memory module, but where that additional module is not part of the triple-channel functionality.  By contrast, it is necessary *to use that functionality* that the memory modules you plan to use **for it** need to come in triplets (or, at least, in three similar batches, depending on how good your memory controllers are).

Basically, her point is that you have presented something that looks like a counterexample to her claim but where you've missed an important aspect of the context in which her claim has been made.  Since your argument only makes sense *because of* missing that contextual aspect, your exception is "proving" her rule.

Comment: Why do you interpret the words "your specific board can operate 4 DIMMs in 3 channels" as "4 DIMMs still cannot operate in 3 channels, even in your case"?

Comment: Are you saying that it is always right to misinterpret the words of you and your opponents as we wish, even when they claim opposite? No matter what we tell, we can always prove our truth by assuming that he assumes something different and we assumed something right. I see the whole infinitude of contexts everybody misses in every dispute now. This is a great Universe of truth, opened by misinterpretation. Thanks for the philosophy. Regarding how good the controllers are, can you please clarify here http://superuser.com/questions/582670/combining-multiple-dimms-in-one-memory-channel